# Autosize text area into tabpane in javaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I hava 3 tabs in a TabPane that each one has a text area with different texts and different length.
I want to autosize text area according to it's length in each tab.
I don't understand what should I do ? using scene builder ? css ?javaFX methods ? 
Thank's in Advance ...

Comment: here is a sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141172/javafx-expandable-textfield-sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are asking that the text areas grow or shrink according to the text that is displayed in them?

If so, see if this code helps:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AutosizingTextArea extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setMinHeight(24);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);
        VBox root = new VBox(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // This code can only be executed after the window is shown:

        // Perform a lookup for an element with a css class of "text"
        // This will give the Node that actually renders the text inside the
        // TextArea
        Node text = textArea.lookup(".text");
        // Bind the preferred height of the text area to the actual height of the text
        // This will make the text area the height of the text, plus some padding
        // of 20 pixels, as long as that height is between the text area's minHeight
        // and maxHeight. The minHeight we set to 24 pixels, the max height will be
        // the height of its parent (usually).
        textArea.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>(){
            @Override
            public Double call() throws Exception {
                return text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
            }
        }, text.boundsInLocalProperty()).add(20));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you want to make this reusable, then you could consider subclassing `TextArea`. (In general, I dislike subclassing control classes.) The tricky part here would be to execute the code that makes the `TextArea` expand once it has been added to a live scene graph (this is necessary for the lookup to work). One way to do this (which is a bit of a hack, imho) is to use an `AnimationTimer` to do the lookup, which you can stop once the lookup is successful. I mocked this up [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/9872945).

Comment: Can you explain about the code much more  ? I want to use it for a tab pane with multiple tabs that each one have a special text .

Comment: Just do the same thing for each TextArea. I'll add some comments in the code, but you can just check the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/) for the methods that I call.

Comment: Yes,I understood it.Thank's. But there isn't any way to do it one time? For example if I have 10 tabs I should do it 10 times .Is there any better way ?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put the code that makes the text area "autosize" into a separate method, and call the method once for each text area. That's still a bit bulky. You could also consider subclassing TextArea. I generally dislike subclassing Controls, but sometimes it's useful. I updated the answer with a link to an example.

Comment: Thank you so much . It was so interesting.But just one more question.How can I get the text of textArea as a Node ? ".text" is a CSS ID ? So how can you assign css ID to text ?

Comment: ".text" is a css class name. It's automatically assigned to any javafx.scene.text.Text object. See the docs for the [lookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) method, and the [CSS guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).